# Lubuntu very slow boot with an SSD for an unknown reason, systemd-analyze not helping

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, ssd, lubuntu

I have a laptop with a 250GB SSD and dual boot Windows 10 and Lubuntu.

Windows takes less than a minute to boot, but Lubuntu takes more than three.

I tried finding the reason why, though systemd-analyze blame says that the service taking more time to load takes only 6 seconds.

```
systemd-analyze blame

       5.920s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
       911ms dev-sda5.device
       409ms snap-repair.service
       266ms systemd-resolved.service
       228ms networking.service
       208ms keyboard-setup.service
       182ms apparmor.service
       147ms upower.service
       138ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       133ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       129ms accounts-daemon.service
       126ms snapd.service
       114ms lightdm.service
       110ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
       108ms NetworkManager.service
        92ms ModemManager.service
        79ms grub-common.service
        77ms preload.service
        ...
```

Although it takes more than 3 minutes to boot:

```
systemd-analyze time

Startup finished in 8.659s (kernel) + 3min 636ms (userspace) = 3min 9.295s
```

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7iHcKXqRfndTUI0Wm1NbFk5LTg/view?usp=sharing) is the `systemd-analyze plot` graph, it shows a huge gap, but it doesn't show any process taking a lot of time.

How can I find out what's causing the system to take so long to boot and how can I improve it?

(this is `systemd-analyze critical-chain`)

```
graphical.target @1min 36.454s
└─multi-user.target @1min 36.454s
 └─whoopsie.service @1min 36.453s
  └─network-online.target @1min 36.453s
   └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 30.532s +5.920s
    └─NetworkManager.service @1min 30.423s +108ms
      └─dbus.service @1min 30.404s
        └─basic.target @1min 30.390s
          └─sockets.target @1min 30.390s
            └─snapd.socket @1min 30.389s +1ms
              └─sysinit.target @1min 30.387s
                └─systemd-timesyncd.service @517ms +133ms
                  └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @421ms +69ms
                    └─systemd-journal-flush.service @404ms +14ms
                      └─systemd-remount-fs.service @376ms +20ms
                        └─system.slice @164ms
                          └─-.slice @146ms
```

**Edit:** Using `dmesg` It's clear that the boot up sequence gets until `crng init done`. Solution posted below

Answer (score 0):

Disabling swap fixed the problem.

Comment out the swap line in `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/crypttab` and reboot.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1685794

Comment: Can you accept your answer and upvote it so the @Community user won't have to bump it to the homepage?